# When I try and boot after installation my system will get to the splash screen and then show a flickering purple screen

Tags: boot

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04, and the install is successful. when I try and boot after installation my system will get to the splash screen and then it goes to a flickering purple screen. Any Ideas how to fix this? My installation of Ubuntu 18.04 went bad before I tried to upgrade.

Comment: How do you know the installation is successful, if it is still installing. Let it finish, then reboot.

Comment: i have done that. It says installation successful, and then it always freezes on a flickering purple screen, no matter what I do.

Comment: You may need to try the safe graphics mode. Is there an Nvidia card somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I have an Nvidia 960 4 GB from Gigabyte

Comment: There are problems with Nvidia, mentioned in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues)

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it to work. I had to check the box next to "Install third party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats". Thank you for your suggestions and help.